# How the thresholds are created while calculating AUC curve?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am confused about how the thresholds are generated in `scikit-learn` in python. For the following example, four thresholds are generated where as when I change the third value in `pred` to `0.6`, the number of thresholds are dropped to 3. Can anyone explain why it is so?

```
#Example 1
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
pred = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8])  #Please note the thord value here is `0.3`
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, pred, pos_label=1)
fpr, tpr, thresholds 


(array([0. , 0.5, 0.5, 1. ]),
 array([0.5, 0.5, 1. , 1. ]),
 array([0.8, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1]))

#Example 2
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
pred = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8])
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, pred, pos_label=1)
fpr, tpr, thresholds 

(array([0., 0., 1.]), 
array([0.5, 1. , 1. ]), 
array([0.8, 0.6, 0.1]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a keyword argument `drop_intermediate` which defaults to True:

> drop_intermediate : boolean, optional (default=True)
>   Whether to drop some suboptimal thresholds which would not appear on a plotted ROC curve. This is useful in order to create lighter ROC curves.
>   New in version 0.17: parameter drop_intermediate.

So changing your code to:

```
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, pred, pos_label=1, drop_intermediate=False)
fpr, tpr, thresholds
```

gives

```
(array([0. , 0. , 0.5, 1. ]),
 array([0.5, 1. , 1. , 1. ]),
 array([0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.1]))
```

You can find this in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html)